# Performance Differences between evaluation boards

Tags: embedded, arm

Our company is a proud owner of a STM32f4 evaluation board ( cortex M4F) ,
We received another evaluation board that is (ARM7TDMI board).

Before starting the migration to the ARM7 evaluation board, we want to know if the hardware is strong enough for us,so we wont waste anytime to discover it later.

Our project utilize many DSP algorithms (that takes advantage of the FPU) , heavy usage of SDIO , and around 1 megabyte of memory  .

So , i was thinking to do the following tests on both evaluation boards ,and see the performance differences  between them :

Math : Addition , Subtraction,Division,Multiplication , Abs and Sqrtf  . It will run i a loop ( and only floating numbers will be used).
SDIO : read/write a 2 kilobyte buffer in a loop
Memory : read/write to the external and internal RAM in a loop.

In your opinion , do this results will give as any indication about the performance differences ,and what  to expect from the "real" project ?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: you should try to craft something similar to what the real program is going to do.  If possible.

Comment: Or run the real program, with fake data (to avoid the need to port the I/O).  But first read the specs of this unidentified alternative part - and is there even enough memory on board?

Comment: Why *"of course around 1 megabyte of memory"*?

Comment: Wow ARM7 time.  Land of the Nintendo GBA.  I didn't know they still made them.  Newer chips the have NEON or similiar SIMD functionality will wipe the floor with this chip.

Comment: Usually, I would not be such a *nay-sayer*.  The Cortex-A5 is going to have similar die area to an *arm926*. See: Arm.com [Cortex-A5](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a5.php).  People often mis-step and pick hardware that may quickly go *end-of-life*.  Make sure the vendor will support the ARM7TDMI.  You are using technology that is years behind, so power and other factor point to better solutions.  Cortex-A5 chips seem to be priced lower than some **connectors**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against any new design based on ARM7 - it is a legacy ARM architecture.  You should check the the vendor's part status and planned obsolescence for any part you intend to design in. No vendor is releasing new designs based on ARM7.

I would also suggest that for DSP algorithms, the DSP features of the Cortex-M4 are more important than its floating point. The ARM Cortex-M CMSIS includes a DSP library that takes advantage of this.  Either way fixed-point DSP algorithms will be far more efficient than using floating point.

Cortex-M is a far more efficient design that ARM7 achieving 1.2 DMIPS per MHz compared to less than 1.0 DMIPS per MHz. That coupled with DSP instructions, floating-point, and separate buses for on-chip flags, RAM and peripherals make most code significantly faster on Cortex-M.

The Cortex-M architecture defines the SYSCLK and interrupt controller, wheras on ARM7 these are defined by the chip vendor and vary between vendors making porting of code between them more difficult.

STM32F4xx parts run at upto 180MHz; Most ARM7 parts are 60MHz or less.

Performing a comparison using floating point is almost pointless.  Floating point hardware will easily outperform software floating point necessary on ARM7 by a factor of 5 to 10 at least.  Unless your application can cope with that drop in performance, it is unsuited to ARM7.  However, most applications do not need floating point.  Integer or fixed point algorithms can run around 5 times faster than software floating point, so compete with hardware floating point.  Remember also that the Cortex-M4 FPU is single precision only.

It would be more reasonable to be comparing Cortex-M3 with Cortex-M4 to test the sensitivity of your application to lack of hardware FP and DSP support.

SDIO performance will be limited by the SDIO interface and the SD card itself (which vary widely in performance even at the same "speed rating") - the load imposed on the processor itself will be very low, or it will spend most of its time waiting for data if your application busy-waits rather than doing something useful while waiting on the SD card.  The use of DMA transfers can make the CPU load more-or-less negligible.

The following diagram illustrates how ARM7 is positioned compared with Cortex-M4.  The latter is both higher performance and greater capability. At the same clock frequency, Cortex-M4 sites between ARM9 and ARM11 on the performance scale.

[image: ARM Processor Comparison]

I do not think that you need to perform any benchmark tests comparing ARM7 and Cortex M4 since the broad performance figures are already available.  What you could perhaps do is measure the CPU load of your existing application on its current platform.  If it is low (perhaps < 20%) and it spends most of its time idle, then ARM7 might be feasible.  Of course if your application is not running on an RTOS or scheduler with an idle task, then measuring true CPU load might be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the M4F would be a far more capable part than the venerable 7TDMI processor.  I have not used an ARM7 with floating point coprocessor and would expect that as you are wanting to do floating point DSP the M4F would be more suited to your application.

Having the floating point in hardware will speed your processing and may allow power savings to be made by slowing the processor clock.

I would be reluctant to start a new design based on a version of the ARM that is at least 10 years old

Comment: Well , the operations that i listed are the most common that is used,there is no way that i can run the original code that is running on the cortex M4 , without heavy modifications,so this is the alternative.

And yes i am aware of the huge differences between both processors, but its not my decision to make , i am only provide the information, and want to know if this test are enough